# Flutter, play store - There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle

Tags: flutter, google-play, flutter-release

I am developing Flutter app. I have build my app as the following:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./debug -v
```

I'm facing the above warning on play store console:

> There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle. If you
> use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will
> make crashes and ANRs easier to analyse and debug.

From android studio [decode an obfuscated stack trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#decode-stack-trace) documentation it seems that I need to upload a `mapping.txt` file.

1. I cannot locate the file in my Flutter project. Where is it?
2. How to upload the file to play store console?

Answer (score 1):

try enabling minify

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

`mapping.txt` file location

```
./app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

Comment: It didn't help. What should the `minifyEnabled` do?

Comment: as its name suggest it shrinks/optimizes the code